# bitmasking and binary arithmetic

Tags: c++, binary, bitmask

I'd like to know the science behind the following. a 32 bit value is shifted left 32 times in a 64 bit type, then a division is performed. somehow the precision is contained within the last 32 bits and in order to retrieve the value as a floating point number, I can multiply by 1 over the max value of an unsigned 32 bit int.

```
phase = ((uint64) 44100 << 32) / 48000;
(phase & 0xffffffff) * (1.0f / 4294967296.0f);// == 0.918749988
```

the same as

```
(float)44100/48000;// == 0.918749988
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `0xffffff` and not `0xffffffff`?

Comment: **−1** Not the real code. Trying your first example in Python the expression `(phase & 0xffffff) * (1.0 / 4294967296.0)` yields `0.0007812499534338713`.

Comment: For the actual example that you've seen somewhere, note that the maximum value of an unsigned 32-bit int is 2^32-1, very close to the factor of 2^32 that you've introduced. So the results (for that original example) would be nearly identical.

Comment: please remove the downvote, i missed 2 digits out, i have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer I was looking for

bit shifting left will provide that number of bits in which to store the precision vale from a division.

dividing the integer value represented by these bits by 2 to the power of the bit shift amount will return the precision value

e.g

0000 0001 * 2^8 = 1 0000 0000 = 256(base 10)

1 0000 0000 / 2 = 1000 0000 = 128(base 10)

128 / 2^8 = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

(...)

1. If you lose precision when dividing two integer numbers, you should remember the remainder.
2. The reminder in C++ can be taken by doing 44100%48000 in your case.
3. Actually these are constants and it's completely clear that 44100/48000 == 0, so remainder is all you have.
4. Well, the reminder will even be -- guess what -- 44100!
5. The `float` type (imposed by the explicit cast) has only 6 significant digits. So `4294967296.0f` will be simply `429496e4` (in mathematics: 429496*10^4). That's why this type isn't valuable for anything but playing around.
6. The best way to get a value of fixed integer type in which all bits are set, and not miss the correct number of 'f' in 0xfffff, is to use the ~ operator and 0 value. In your case, ~uint32_t(0).

Well, I should have said this in the beginning: `44100.0/48000` should give you the result you want. :P

Comment: my question isnt why I lose precision, it's what is the process involved in this style of division.

Comment: So what's your question then? Your statement in the "question" is too unclear to guess what you want to know. Does point #5 answer it?